# Python: dictionary list comprehension for count of number of instances

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following:

```
a = rand(100).round() #for example
count = {}

for i in a:
    count[i] = count.get(i, 0) + 1

# print(a)
print(count)
```

The last line returns something like `{0.0: 52, 1.0: 48}`

I would like to do the for loop as dictionary comprehension. But,

```
count = {i: count.get(i,0)+1 for i in a}
```

always returns `{0.0: 1, 1.0: 1}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting rand and round from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
count = {i: count.get(i,0)+1 for i in a}
```

is composed of two parts:

```
{i: count.get(i,0)+1 for i in a}
```

and

```
count = ...
```

the first one computes a dictionary and when evaluating it `count` is just the empty dictionary you defined first and has no relation with the dictionary being constructed by the comprehension expression.

Only at the end of the dictionary construction this is assigned to `count` (replacing the empty dictionary). During the comprehension evaluation `count` is empty and remains empty so every `get` will always return the default value of 0.

There is no way to refer to the object being constructed in a comprehension (e.g a list or a dictionary) in the expressions used inside the comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the appropriately named `Counter`?

```
from collections import Counter

>>> c = Counter([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,4,3,2,3,4,1,3,13,12,13,2,1,13,4,4,4])
>>> c
Counter({1: 14, 4: 5, 3: 3, 13: 3, 2: 2, 5: 1, 12: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the comprehension version of yours look like this,

```
count = {}
count = {i: count.get(i,0)+1 for i in a}
```

When the comprehension is executed, `count` refers to the empty dictionary created in the previous line. So `count.get(i,0)` always returns `0`. That is why the result has `1` always. If you didn't defined in the previous line, you will get

> NameError: global name 'count' is not defined

Because the `count` is not defined yet in the program.

**Note:** You cannot reference the dictionary being constructed in the dictionary comprehension.

So, updating the dictionary will not work in the comprehension. The solution what you actually have now is fine.